# Can I lose datagrams in the socket receive buffer and how can it happen when I use UDP?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, ethernet, tcp

I want to use UDP sockets under a reliable transport in my C-programm, and I want to know more where packet can be lost also.

As we known UDP is not reliable protocol. This is mean that:

- if data packet lost in any low-level protocol, then it will not be sent again
- data packet can lost in the receive buffer, for example if receive buffer is overflowing

I'm interested in the second case - how does it work?
In the receive buffer datagrams are recorded along with the size of datagrams, 
because UDP guarantees the preservation of message boundaries. And when receive buffer is overflowing, then first datagram remove:

1. read first 8 bytes from head of ring buffer (receive buffer), which
   contain datagram size
2. move head of the ring buffer by the amount equal to the size of the
   message - i.e. move head to the next datagram
3. if free space in the ring buffer enough for new received datagram,
   then write it to ring buffer and move tail to the end of it, else
   goto 1 step

I.e. this mean that when I call to read from socket, then happens a system call, with access to such ring buffer in kernel space, where it reads first 8 bytes for datagram size, and then reads datagram with this size, isn't it?

Is it right?

**OS: Linux x86_64 (RedHat 6)**

Comment: Are you interested in OS internals? In that case you'd need to specify the OS. This is an implementation detail that does not follow from the UDP spec.

Comment: I think the second case should be self-explanatory. If the receive buffer is full, it cannot receive new packets, so new packets are ignored until the app reads from the buffer to free up room for new packets. Simple as that.

Comment: @usr  OS Linux x86_64 (for example RedHat6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And when receive buffer is overflowing, then [the] first datagram [is] remove[d]

No. When a datagram arrives and the receive buffer is already full, the *new* datagram is dropped. Processing of the buffer doesn't occur at all.

Comment: Thank you! Is this true for any OS, or usually it happens, but not necessarily?

Comment: I don't have any information about what different operating systems do, but I don't see any reason to believe any OS would choose to process the input buffer in the laborious manner you describe when they could simply just drop the incoming packet instead.